# Keep the format options always set to a particular value

Tags: vim

I've noticed that plugins and other things will often modify `formatoptions`. is the following sufficient to keep them set/static?

```
" Do not auto-wrap comments and don't insert comments when pressing o/O. See: :h *fo-table* and :h *'formatoptions'*
set formatoptions-=cro
autocmd Filetype * set formatoptions-=cro
```

Or, is this missing anything? (Is the first line unnecessary as well?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you have is (almost) good. You need to wrap it in proper `augroup`

```
augroup FORMATOPTIONS
  autocmd!
  autocmd filetype * set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o " Disable continuation of comments to the next line
augroup END
```

Also notice as I divided `-cro` into singular option removing, otherwise you won't have guarantee you get the desired effect.

Comment: thanks for this. In the above, what's the use of having it in an `augroup` though? Wouldn't it essentially do the same thing either way, or why is that useful in this case?

Comment: @David542 Check [Why should I use augroup?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9455/25807)

Comment: right, but sourcing `-=cro` multiple times would have no effect, no? i.e., if `c` is there it would remove it, and if `c` is not there, nothing happens, right?

Comment: `-=cro` will take effect only if those options are exactly in that order. If `fo=roc`, then `-=cro` won't work